# JWPlayer is showing "Error loading media: File could not be played" in ios webview

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am using latest jwplayer in my webpage and loading valid mp4 video in ios webview and safari, and its showing error on player that "Error loading media: File could not be played", same webpage and video works fine when I do that from android chrome browser or from desktop browser.

Can anybody help in this?????

```
jwplayer('embedVideo').setup({
                file: videoUrl,
                image: imageUrl,
                width: '100%',
                aspectratio: '16:9',
                controls: true
            });
```

Comment: Please give us a link to your site. The code looks fine, so there's something else going on.

Comment: Videos from the link given in above comment works fine in android and desktop browsers but not in iphone.

Comment: Try to test with this sample media file to see if it works - http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-364766.mp4

Comment: This video works fine from my page, but not others . . . . .

Comment: Got it resolved, issue was in our video serving with jersey.

Comment: Glad you got it working.